# how to pass parameters to a predicate in command prompt using swi prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

i'm new to swi prolog and i'd like to pass the arguments in the command line. i actually wrote a program that solves sudoku and i pass my matrix in the code but i'd like to do it from there If possible, I would like to learn to do it in general.
 if you have any methods, tutorials or links that could, please help me share with me.

thank you in advance

```
:- use_module(library('clp/bounds')).
:- use_module(library('clp/clp_distinct')).

sudoku(Grid, Vars) :-
Vars = 
[
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9,
B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9,
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,
D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,
E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,
F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,
G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,
H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9,
I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9
  ],

 Vars in 1..9,
 vars_in(Vars, 1, 9),

 all_distinct([A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9]),
 all_distinct([B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9]),
 all_distinct([C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9]),
 all_distinct([D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9]),
 all_distinct([E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9]),
 all_distinct([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9]),
 all_distinct([G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9]),
 all_distinct([H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6,H7,H8,H9]),
 all_distinct([I1,I2,I3,I4,I5,I6,I7,I8,I9]),

 all_distinct([A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1]),
 all_distinct([A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2]),
 all_distinct([A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3]),
 all_distinct([A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4]),
 all_distinct([A5,B5,C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5]),
 all_distinct([A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6]),
 all_distinct([A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7]),
 all_distinct([A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8]),
 all_distinct([A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9]),

 all_distinct([A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3]),
 all_distinct([A4,A5,A6,B4,B5,B6,C4,C5,C6]),
 all_distinct([A7,A8,A9,B7,B8,B9,C7,C8,C9]),
 all_distinct([D1,D2,D3,E1,E2,E3,F1,F2,F3]),
 all_distinct([D4,D5,D6,E4,E5,E6,F4,F5,F6]),
 all_distinct([D7,D8,D9,E7,E8,E9,F7,F8,F9]),
 all_distinct([G1,G2,G3,H1,H2,H3,I1,I2,I3]),
 all_distinct([G4,G5,G6,H4,H5,H6,I4,I5,I6]),
 all_distinct([G7,G8,G9,H7,H8,H9,I7,I8,I9]),

 printGrid(Vars).

 grid([],[]) :- !.
 grid([0|Q1],[_|Q2]) :-
 !,
 grid(Q1,Q2).


 grid([Val|Q1],[Var|Q2]) :-
 !,
 vars_in([Var], [Val]),
 grid(Q1,Q2).

sudokuExemple(Vars) :-
sudoku(
[ 8,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,9,
  0,0,9,0,0,0,1,0,0,
  1,0,0,3,0,2,0,0,7,
  0,5,0,1,0,4,0,8,0,
  0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,
  0,1,0,7,0,9,0,2,0,
  5,0,0,4,0,3,0,0,8,
  0,0,3,0,0,0,4,0,0,
  4,0,6,0,0,0,3,0,1
  ], Vars
 ).



 printGrid(G) :- 
 printHSep(3),
 printGrid(G,1,1).

 printGrid(G,L,10) :- 
 !,
 printHSep(L),
 L1 is L + 1,
 printGrid(G,L1,1).

 printGrid([],_,_) :- !.

 printGrid([T|Q],L,C) :- 
 write(T),
 printVSep(C),
 C1 is C + 1,
 printGrid(Q,L,C1).


 printVSep(C) :- 
 mult3(C), !,

 write('|').

 printVSep(_) :- write(',').


 printHSep(L) :- 
 mult3(L), !,
 nl, write('==================='), nl,
 write('|').

printHSep(_) :-
nl, write('|').


mult3(C) :- 
T is (C mod 3),
T == 0.
```

Comment: Might want to check out [the optparse library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=optparse) and see the [-g command line option](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdline#sec:2.4.4) to pass goals to SWI.

Comment: You are using a very old version of the clp-libraries - they are full of bugs. Instead upgrade to a more recent version such that you can say `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`

Comment: thank you Daniel Lyons, I visited these links but it did not help me to solve my problem